# Dual quaternion inverse

Tags: inverse, quaternions, clifford-algebras

Is it true that for every dual quaternion $Q$ I can find it's inverse such that $QQ^{-1} = 1?$
Using the usual definition $Q^{-1}=\frac{Q^{*}}{||Q||^2}$ doesn't work for me, since the dual part doesn't generally cancel out, and also $QQ^{-1}Q {\neq} {Q} $

At least, that's what my implementation in code says.

Comment: That "usual definition" only works when you know that $\|Q\|^2$ is invertible. This is the case in the quaternions since we know the nonzero reals are invertible. In the dual quaternions, it does fail to be invertible sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the dual quaternions contain zero divisors, one of which is a nonzero element $\epsilon$ with square zero. Such elements cannot have inverses.

It turns out that the units are exactly the $a+\epsilon b$ where $a$ is nonzero. To see this, first notice that $1+\epsilon b$ has the obvious inverse $1-\epsilon b$. Suppose now $a\neq0$. Then $1+\epsilon ba^{-1}$ is a unit, and so is its product with $a$, which is $a+\epsilon b$ . Working through this, it's easy to see why $a^{-1}(1-\epsilon ba^{-1})$ is the inverse of $a+\epsilon b$ .

Trying to establish an inverse with the formula you gave would be circular since you need to establish the inverse of $\|Q\|^2$ before you can divide by it, and that is, generally, just some other dual quaternion.

If the inverse of Q exists, then $QQ^{-1}Q=Q$. The product of the first two things is $1$, and the product of $1$ with Q is Q. If you believe in associativity and multiplicative identity in the dual quaternions, and you know the definition of inverse, it has to hold.

Comment: Isn't the quantity $||Q||^2$ a dual scalar rather than dual quaternion, though?

Comment: @user144345 you might be able to say that, but I don't think it's a useful distinction here. $QQ^*$ is an element of the dual quaternions since the dq's are closed under multiplication.

Comment: @user144345 does "dual scalar" just mean an element of the form $a+\epsilon b$ where $a,b$ are both real numbers?

Comment: @user144345 I guess it must mean that. Yes, they're of that form, but those are also dual quaternions.

Comment: Of course you're right. I as a humble programmer tend to give special treatment to scalars it seems.

Answer (score 0):

There are useful applications of dual quaternions to geometry and mechanics that use assignments and interpretations that constrain the forms and tame the unruliness.

Nomenclature:

- dual quantity *d* = a + ε b, ε ≠ 0, ε² = 0.
  The monstrously confusing industry standard is to call a and b the 'real' and 'dual' parts, but I'll call them the 'primary' and 'secondary' parts.
- dual sum *d*<sub>1</sub> + *d*<sub>2</sub> = (a<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>2</sub>) + ε (b<sub>1</sub> + b<sub>2</sub>)
- dual product *d*<sub>1</sub> *d*<sub>2</sub> = (a<sub>1</sub> a<sub>2</sub>) + ε (a<sub>1</sub> b<sub>2</sub> + b<sub>1</sub> a<sub>2</sub>)
- dual conjugate *d** = (a + ε b)* = (a - ε b)
- dual norm = |*d*| = √(*d* *d**) = √(a<sup>2</sup> + ε (a b - b a))
  If (a b) is commutative then |*d*| = √a<sup>2</sup>
- dual inverse 1/*d* = (1/a + ε ((1/a) b (1/a)) if a has an inverse
- quaternion U = {u, **u**}, u a one-dimension form, **u** a three-vector.
- quaternion conjugate U<sup>*</sup> = {u, -**u**}
- quaternion norm |U| = √(U U<sup>*</sup>)
- unit quaternion |U| = 1
- unit vector quaternion {0, **u**}, |**u**|=1.
- dual quaternion ***Q*** = U + ε V
- dual quaternion inverse ***Q***<sup>-1</sup> = (U<sub>0</sub> + ε V<sub>0</sub>)
  (U + ε V) (U<sub>0</sub> + ε V<sub>0</sub>) = 1
  1.) U U<sub>0</sub> = 1,
  U<sub>0</sub> = U*

  2.) V U<sub>0</sub> + U V<sub>0</sub> = 0
  = V U* + U V<sub>0</sub>,
  V<sub>0</sub> = - U* V U*
  ***Q***<sup>-1</sup> = (U* - ε U* V U*)

An example is the system described by Michael McCarthy [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262132524) and loosely interpreted below.

In the usual way, a unit vector quaternion U expresses a direction, R its *spherical transform* about the origin, a rotation expressed as a quaternion product:

U<sub>2</sub> = R<sub>12</sub> U<sub>1</sub> R<sub>12</sub><sup>*</sup>
R<sub>12</sub> = {cos(θ/2), sin(θ/2) **n**}, where θ = the rotation angle and **n** = the axis vector direction.

The norm of R = 1 and R<sup>-1</sup> = R<sup>*</sup>

Exploiting the constrained forms and the condition that the rotation axis **n** is normal to both **u**<sub>1</sub> and **u**<sub>2</sub>, the rotation quaternion R<sub>12</sub> can be computed directly, given U<sub>1</sub> and U<sub>2</sub> as

R<sub>12</sub> = √(U<sub>2</sub> U<sub>1</sub><sup>*</sup>)

A *dual quaternion line* has both orientation and position in space. It's defined as ***L*** = U + ε V, where U as above is a dimensionless unit vector quaternion with **u** expressing the line's orientation and where V is a vector quaternion with units of length, the vector  **v** expressing the moment of the line about the origin.

By the nature of the geometrical definition, **u**.**v** = 0., |***L***| = 1 and ***L***<sup>-1</sup> = ***L***<sup>*</sup>.

As an example of the form, a line in direction **u** passing through point **p**, the dual quaternion expression is 
***L*** = {0, **u**} + ε {0, **p** × **u**}

Any rigid spatial transform can be resolved to a *screw transform* - a combined rotation about and translation along an axis. Dual quaternion lines can undergo rigid transformations, combining rotation and translation, by a *screw quaternion* of the form ***Q*** = {cos(*θ*/2),  sin(*θ*/2) ***n***), where *θ* is a dual angle, the primary part being the angle of rotation, the secondary part being the translation distance measured along the axis, and ***n*** a dual vector, the primary part being the direction of the rotation axis and the secondary part the moment of the axis line about the origin.

***L***<sub>2</sub> = ***Q***<sub>12</sub> ***L***<sub>1</sub> ***Q***<sub>12</sub><sup>*</sup>

Again, because of the constrained forms and recognizing that the screw axis {0, ***n***} intersects and is normal to both ***L***<sub>1</sub> and ***L***<sub>2</sub>, this equation can be solved directly for ***Q***<sub>12</sub>

***Q***<sub>12</sub> = √(***L***<sub>2</sub> ***L***<sub>1</sub>*)

In computation, it seems to be an advantage to perform these functions on their matrix forms, expressing both the geometric objects and their transformations as octonions.

--
Fred Klingener